# R - factor examcard has new levels

Tags: r, classification, predict, training-data, test-data

I built a classification model in R using C5.0 given below:

```
library(C50)
library(caret)
a = read.csv("All_SRN.csv")
set.seed(123)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(a$anatomy, p = .70, list = FALSE)
training <- a[ inTrain,]
test <- a[-inTrain,]
Tree <- C5.0(anatomy ~ ., data = training, 
            trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 10,
                                     classProb = TRUE))
TreePred <- predict(Tree, test)
```

The training set has features like - `examcard, coil_used, anatomy_region, bodypart_anatomy and anatomy`(target class). All the features are categorical variables. There are a total of 10k odd values, I divided the data into training and test data. The learner worked great with this **training** and **test** set partioned in 70:30 ratio, but the problem comes when I provide the test set with new values given below:

```
TreePred <- predict(Tree, test_add)
```

Here, **test_add** contains the already present test set and a set of new values and on executing the learner fails to classify the new values and throws the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(object$Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, : factor examcard has new levels
```

I tried to merge the new factor levels with the existing one using:

```
Tree$xlevels[["examcard"]] <- union(Tree$xlevels[["examcard"]], levels(test_add$examcard))
```

But, this wasn't of much help since the code executed with the following message and didn't yield any fruitful result:

```
predict code called exit with value 1
```

The feaure examcard holds a good deal of primacy in the classification hence can't be ignored. How can these set of values be classified?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a prediction for factor levels in your test set that are absent in your training set.  Your model will not have coefficients for these new factor levels.

If you are doing a 70/30 split, you need to repartition your data using `caret::CreateDataPartition`...

... or your own stratified sample function to ensure that all levels are represented in the training set:  use the "split-apply-combine" approach: split the data set by examcard, and for each subset, apply the split, then combine the training subsets and the testing subsets.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493920/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-partition-has-representative-observations-from-each-leve) for more details.

Comment: I used `caret::CreateDataPartition` to partition my dataset. I also used `stringAsFactors = FALSE` while I read my CSV file since in case of factors the levels would be pre-defined and the learner would fail to recognize any new data that is passed to it. Having that, the learner `C50::C5.0` recognizes only factor outcomes.

Comment: @NeelimaSeshadri You should include your `CreateDataPartition` statement in your question, since this is the root of your problem.  You should consider stratifying on `examcard` (or possibly a dummy factor like `paste(anatomy,examcard,sep="#")` to preserve class balance, depending on the size of your dataset).  Also, you should consider factorizing `examcard` and other variables prior to partitioning so that the levels are consistent between the training and testing datasets.

Comment: What about the values that are absent completely in the training set but present in test set. That would still not be included in the stratified sample, right?

Comment: @NaiveBabes I don't think you're understanding me.  The stratification is part of the partitioning process (applies to 100% of the data).  Then you will ensure that every level of the factor appears in both the training (70%) and the test set (30%).  The only case this might be a problem is if the level is extremely infrequent (appears only 1-3 times in data set).  You could manually force those into the training set.

Comment: I understand what you suggested. I'm trying to validate the model with data that has new set of values. I already tested the model with training and test that was partitioned earlier into 70:30, I'm now providing the model with values having same instances but different values something that wasn't present in both training and test. Also, do you mean to say if a value is unknown to the learner it has to be stratified again so that it's part of the training data? My apologies if this is complicated