# R - test data unavailable in training data for classification

Tags: r, classification, training-data, test-data

For any classification algorithm, can the test data of nominal values contain new set of values unavailable in the training data set?

For example:
If the training has the following values with occupation as target class:

```
Name        Location        Occupation
John        New York        Engineer
John        Minnesota       Doctor
David       New York        Engineer
Alex        California      Engineer
```

And, if the test data is:

```
Kevin       Bangalore       Engineer
```

Will Kevin be classified correctly since it's not available in the training data? If no, should the classification be rebuilt with this new value?

Comment: I think in `Kenvin` case. It could be correct or not. It depend on your sample data and the accuracy of your model. For your question, you do not need to rebuild with new value.

Comment: I'm using `C50::C5.0` as my classification algorithm, when I divide the entire dataset into training and test the accuracy is pretty high but when I give a new value in the test data the algorithm fails to classify it and stops at the place where the new data appears.

Comment: Can you take a test sample such that there are no new categorical values?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - With no new categorical values, the algorithm works fine with 95% accuarcy, I assume that is because the learner has the knowledge of all the features and it's attributes in the dataset. I wanted know if or not remodelling is necessary for correct classification in case of new data.

Comment: If new data/observations come in, then your classification model could potentially change.  This means that you might have to rebuild the model, and then cross-validate against the test set.  If you give more details, I can provide a more detailed response.

Comment: @Tim - The dataset has 6 instances namely - SRN number, examcard, coil_name, anatomic_region, body_part, anatomy(target class). There are a total of 10k entries/attributes in my CSV. This dataset was then divided into training and test data using in 70:30 ratio using `caret::createDataPartition`. The learner `C50::C5.0` executed with 95% accuracy. 
I then wanted to test the model with values that were not part of either the training or test data, with same instances but different attributes.

Comment: Contd..
For instance: if the initial dataset had SRN values ranging from 1 to 10, the new test set has 11 through 15, similarily for other instances. When this test set was tested against the model the values were either predicted incorrectly or execution terminated with `predict code called exit with value 1` for `predict` function. My question was if or not I've to remodel the existing model with the new values or is there a trick that deals with the new values that come in.

Comment: @Tim - I've posted another question that lead to this query where the factors in the new test set has new levels when compared to the original dataset. Please find this link: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402819/r-factor-examcard-has-new-levels)